# is it possible to display image files that require a session on the server in chromecast?

Tags: image, chromecast

I have an app that has user generated images, but to access these images, you need to log into the server, otherwise, if you try to access an image URL, you're redirected to the login page.

Is it possible to show these images in chromecast? The documentation only show examples using public URLs.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using the chrome sender only, not the android or iOS sender, and that, if possible, I'd like to use the default receiver.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to login the user on your sender app and have your server create a (short lived) token or so and pass that back to your sender. Then pass along that token to chromecast and have chromecast use the token. For example, send a URL like "https://some.url.com/my-image.png?token=1234assadasfcrafctvawr32w34v" to your server, from chromecast, and have your server interpret that appropriately.

I am sure you can think of more sophisticated approaches but that is the basic idea.